# fgets reading very slow compared to socket_recv

Tags: php, sockets, fgets

I've been having issues with reading data from a Python socket server. I've tried several methods and have been searching for a solution for months.

The response I am trying to get from the Python socket server is different every time. It can be 40 characters the first time and over 10k characters the next.

I've tried to use **[socket_recv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-recv.php)** and **[fgets()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)** and so far **fgets** works the best for what I need, as **socket_recv** doesn't get the whole response when **fgets** does. There's just one problem. It's so much slower compared to **socket_recv**, and doesn't always get the response.

The problem I am having with **fgets** is that it takes **2.02** seconds to get the response on a local connection, no matter how big or small it is. 
I need it to go down, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it..
Connecting to the Python socket server only takes **22ms**, so I don't get why it'd take long at all to get the whole reponse.

Oh and if it helps, the response is a JSON string.

**Here's the code I use:**

```
/*
 * Recieve
 */
public function recv() {
    if (!$this->connected()) {
        $this->_errorStr = 'Recieve timeout';
        $this->_error = true;

        return false;
    }

    $buf = '';        
    while ($line = fgets($this->_socket)) {
        $buf .= $line;
    }

    return json_decode($buf);
}
```

*And if you need the whole class:*

```
class Sockets {
    /*
     * Variables
     */
    private $_id,
            $_name,
            $_ip,
            $_port,
            $_socket,
            $_socketTimeout = 1,
            $_triedConnect = false,
            $_errorStr = '',
            $_error = false;

    /*
     * Construct class
     */
    public function __construct($ip, $port) {
        $this->_ip = $ip;
        $this->_port = $port;
        $this->_socket = false;
    }

    /*
     * Send command
     */
    public function command($cmd, $json = true) {
        if ($json) {
            $cmd = json_encode($cmd);
        }
        if (!$this->send($cmd)) {
            return $this->_errorStr;
        }
        $r = $this->recv();
        if (!$r) {
            return $this->_errorStr;
        }

        return $r;
    }

    /*
     * Connect to server
     */
    public function connect() {
        $this->_error = false;
        if ($this->_triedConnect) {
            $this->_errorStr = 'Failed to connect.';
            $this->_error = true;

            return false;
        }

        $this->_triedConnect = true;
        $this->_errorStr = '';
        $errno = 0;
        $errstr = '';

        $this->_socket = @pfsockopen($this->_ip, $this->_port, $errno, $errstr, $this->_socketTimeout);
        if (!$this->_socket) {
            $this->_errorStr = sprintf('Can\'t connect to server.. (%errno: %errstr)', $errno, $errstr);
            $this->_error = true;
            $this->_socket = false;

            return false;
        }
        stream_set_timeout($this->_socket, $this->_socketTimeout);

        // Clear stream
        while ($this->dataReady()) {
            if (!fgets($this->_socket)) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!$this->connected()) {
            $this->_errorStr = 'Lost connection to server!';
            $this->_error = true;
            $this->_socket = false;

            return $this->_errorStr;
        }

        return true;
    }

    /*
     * Authentication
     */
    public function auth() {

    }

    /*
     * Connected
     */
    public function connected() {
        return $this->_socket !== false;
    }

    /*
     * Data ready
     */
    public function dataReady() {
        if (!$this->connected()) {
            return false;
        }

        return @stream_select($r = array($this->_socket), $w = null, $x = null, 0) > 0;
    }

    /*
     * Send data
     */
    public function send($data) {
        if (!$this->connected()) {
            $this->_errorStr = 'Not connected!';
            $this->_error = true;

            return false;
        }

        if (@fwrite($this->_socket, $data) === false) {
            $this->_errorStr = 'Failed to send command!';
            $this->_error = true;

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * Recieve
     */
    public function recv() {
        if (!$this->connected()) {
            $this->_errorStr = 'Recieve timeout';
            $this->_error = true;

            return false;
        }

        $buf = '';        
        while ($line = fgets($this->_socket)) {
            $buf .= $line;
        }

        return json_decode($buf);
    }

    /*
     * Disconnect
     */
    public function disconnect() {
        if (!$this->connected()) {
            return;
        }

        fclose($this->_socket);
        $this->_socket = false;
        $this->_triedConnect = false;
    }
}
```

Any help is really appreciated!

---

**EDIT**

The machine I am using is running Windows 8.1 Pro, with Media Center.

I am using **Python 2.7.9** for the server with the following dependencies installed:

```
psutil   <- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/psutil
colorama <- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/colorama
pycrypto <- http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto
```

It shouldn't matter what type of TCP socket server at all. Just a basic one should work just to test this. Even without the dependencies. Something like [this](http://www.binarytides.com/python-socket-server-code-example/) works.

For PHP I am using [Wamp](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) and **PHP 5.5.12** with the following modules enabled:

```
php_bz2
php_com_dotnet
php_curl
php_exif
php_fileinfo
php_gd2
php_gettext
php_gmp
php_imap
php_intl
php_ldap
php_mbstring
php_mysql
php_mysqli
php_openssl
php_pdo_mysql
php_pdo_sqlite
php_shmop
php_soap
php_sockets
php_sqlite3
php_xmlrpc
php_xsl
```

Some, if not all of those, are enabled on default.

To test the Sockets class, all you need is to is something like this:

```
// Import class file
require_once 'Sockets.php';
$socket = new Sockets('127.0.0.1', 21); // Change the port accordingly

// Connect to socket server
$socket->connect();

// Now in my case, the socket server responds to JSON strings, and nothing else.
// So I am going to show you show I send a command.
$command = array(
    'key' => 'encrypted key', // This key is to do some validation on the server-side
    'command' => 'command' // This is the command to be issued.
);

// Send command to socket server and dump the response
var_dump($socket->command($command));

// To send a plainstring command use this instead
var_dump($socket->command('command here', false));
```

Comment: What does your test environment consist of. i.e what server are you connecting to? Have you tried using some of the 'example' code from the various python tutorials available? Please update your question with the responses rather than posting comments. The tcp/ip stuff is normally very reliable. The 2 seconds delay may be some sort of timeout issue. That is just a guess.

Comment: Question updated @RyanVincent

Comment: You misunderstood what i asked for. First, if i decide to 'have a go' at your 'problem'. You need to know that i run it on a windows XP pc with whatever version of 'python' i have installed (2.7.8) and PHP 5.3.18. Now if your code works fine - will that help you?  I suspect not. You need to specify, in detail, your version of python, operating system and what server software you are using your 'Sockets' class to access. I also need your 'test cases'.

Comment: Really sorry about that! Pro-tip; Don't do anything whilst tired.. I think I've updated the question with everything you need. If I forgot something, please let me know. I really appreciate you at least considering to help @RyanVincent!

Comment: That looks like enough information to go on :-) I will 'have' a go' over the next couple of daya and will let you know the results.

Comment: Thanks @RyanVincent, I really do appreciate it! Take your time! :)

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite a lot of debugging and further searching the interwebs and not finding anything, I finally found an answer to my issue.

---

The issue was with the Python socket server. After sending a command to the socket server, it sends a response back with the requested data. The socket server *should* then close the connection. And this is where the issue was. It was sending the response, but not closing the connection, so all I had to do was close the connection after every command. The response time went from **2.02** seconds down to **20ms**, which is what I wanted.